# Building Android in ionic failed with transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug for process okhttp-3.13.1.jar

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, ionic2

While trying to build an android platform in ionic 2 after updating android studio this error started showing up.

```
  Ionic Info:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> ```
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ’:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug’. >
> ```
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>
> ```
> Failed to process /.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.13.1/b49cf3799bd473199e96c4fb9987e9e08395a1c0/okhttp-3.13.1.jar
> ```

Found that Dexbuilder error is related to Java version 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying these options in "Build.Gradle" file inside /platforms/android folder solved the issue

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```